# Proxy wizards: Can it be done? Passthru WebDAV proxy using digest auth inbound and basic auth outbound - for Windows 7 web folders

Tags: authentication, proxy, webdav, windows-7-x64

I have a problem, along with several thousand of my close friends.

I am using Windows 7 x64 and I want to have a web folder so I can drag and drop files from my local machine to my web site.

Apparently, most (non-MS) WebDAV sites use Basic auth, but the WebDAV client in Win7 *really really really* wants to use Digest auth.  Win7 WebDAV client just does not do Basic auth.  Just google "WebDAV Windows 7" and you will see how many people feel my pain.

It would be really nice if the cPanel people would fix their WebDAV to play nice with Win7, but I'm not going to hold my breath.

So I got the idea that I could use a proxy of some sort.  On my local machine, I could set it up to give the Win7 WebDAV client the Digest auth it wants, then pass on a Basic auth request with pre-canned credentials.  Everything else would just pass through.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Digest, is that the password is hashed. So the only way your proxy knows the password to send in the Basic auth header is if you store the passwords on the proxy.

If you're willing to make this sacrifice, and comfortable with writing a custom, simple proxy for this this will work.

Evert